# Installing a new ceiling fan to old wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

What I found… In the junction box in the ceiling there were two white wires (twisted tightly together) capped together with one white wire from the light fixture. It looked pretty crowded in that cap.  The black wire in the ceiling was capped together to the black wire from the light. The ground on the light fixture was not attached. It was just dangling loose in the light housing.  The light has always worked perfectly.

I bought a ceiling fan to replace the light.  When I installed the ceiling fan, I connected the one white wire to the two white wires in the ceiling (found twisted tightly together) into one cap, just like I found them to be when I opened the box when the light fixture was connected.  I then attached the black wires together in one cap.  I don’t see a ground wire in the box.  Or could one of the white wires that are twisted together be the ground?  I attached the ground wire from the fan to a metal piece of the junction box.  Was this a mistake?

Moving forward.  I finished installing the fan.  I turned the power back on and the light on the fan flashes about every 3 to 5 seconds.  That’s it.  Nothing more.  The fan does not move.  I have not checked the wiring in the wall junction box.  There’s currently a dimmer there that is used to operate the ceiling fan that I replaced.

Should I remove the wall plate and install a simple on and off switch?  To me, it seems like the dimmer switch could be the issue.

Also, as I mentioned earlier, I found two white wires that were twisted together in the ceiling junction box and capped together with the one white wire from the light fixture.  I’ve always been told by handymen/electricians, leave it how you found it.  Meaning, if it was working before without any issues, then try to re-wire the same way.

I guess my question is; How do I go about correcting what I’ve started?  I’ve installed ceiling fans before where they have worked fine.  But most were older fans that had an assigned junction box on the wall. Match up the wiring and grounds and away you go.  This newer fan has a remote and no wall switch.

Comment: *There’s currently a dimmer there that is used to operate the ceiling fan that I replaced.* It has a wall switch - the dimmer. But you can't use a dimmer with a fan in general (because motors don't work the same as lights) and for sure not with a remote. Replace the dimmer with a plain switch and (if the fan/remote works that way) you can use the remote as long as the switch is  on and when you turn the switch off then it goes all off and when you turn it on, *ideally* it will go back to previous setting.

Comment: If the fan has a pull chain it may be set to off.  Also  you cannot use a dimmer with a fan.